# Export: links in headings missing

Tags: org-mode, org-publish

When I have something todo regarding to a URL, I often just capture the URL, e.g. like this:

```
** TODO [[http://example.org/foo/bar]]
```

But this leads to the problem, that I get empty headings when I `org-publish` my org files.

Am I doing something wrong? I understand that a link in a heading is a problem since the headings itself are links, on the other hand just leaving them out is not a very good solution. Is there a workaround? The URL as unlinked text would be a viable solution for me.